# Unit testing asp.net MVC controller with constructor injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

How do i setup my test project so that i can unit test my controllers,
I'm not able to call my controller actions from test method as it requires dependent interface object.
I don't want to implement any mock repository.
I want to use my existing database repository and business logic available same as integration testing.

My Project Structure is as below:

- MVC.Web
- MVC.BL (Interface and implementation)
- MVC.Repository (Interface and implementation)

Repository Example:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IBaseUOW<DBEntitiesEntities> _dbContext;
    private readonly IBaseRepository<User> _userRepository;

    public UserRepository(IBaseUOW<MoynoECTNewEntities> dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _userRepository = dbContext.GetRepository<User>();
    }

    public UserResponse GetUserList()
    {
        var response = new UserResponse {Acknowledge = AcknowledgeType.Success};

        var typeList = _userRepository.Get().OrderBy(x => x.UserName).ToList();

        response.UserList = typeList.ToList();

        return response;
    }
}
```

Business Layer Example:

```
public class UserBL : IUserBL
{
    public UserResponse GetUserList()
    {
        var response = new UserResponse();

        var userList = _userRepository.GetUserList();
        if (userList != null && userList.UserList.Count > 0)
        {
            response.UserList = userList.UserList.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            response.Message = "No Data Found";
            response.Acknowledge = AcknowledgeType.Failure;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Controller Example:

```
public class AdminController : BaseController
{
    public readonly IUserBL _userBl;
    public readonly IUserRoleBL _userRoleBl;

    public AdminController(IUserRoleBL userRoleBl, IUserBL userBl)
    {
        _userRoleBl = userRoleBl;
        _userBl = userBl;
    }

    public ActionResult GetUserList()
    {
        var response = _userBl.GetUserList();
        return View("_GridViewUser", response.UserList);
    }
}
```

My unit test method example:

```
[TestClass]
public class AdminControllerTest
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void Check_UserMaster_ViewName()
    {
       //assemple
        var controller = // how to call controller ?
       // act
        var result= // controller.GetUserList() as ViewResult;
       // assert
        Assert.AreEqual("UserMaster", result.ViewName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to implement mock repository and directly want to use my existing database repository

Well I think that's the wrong approach since you're *unit testing* the class, meaning all dependencies should not impact the validity of the test, but that's your call.

Just pass in an instance of the "real" repository in your test.

```
var userRoleBL = new UserBL();
var userBL = new UserRoleBL();
var controller = new AdminController(userRoleBL, userBL);
// test the controller
```

Comment: @D Stanley, sorry i didn't provide above my proper business logic constructor

constructor is overloaded with repository interface,

in that case what to do?

Comment: So pass in a `UserRepository` to your `UserBL`.  Same principle - you need to include all dependencies if you decide not to mock.  If those dependencies have dependencies as well, you'll need to include them.

Comment: Note that if you mock the `IUserBL` you don't have to reference a repository :)

Answer (score 0):

As @D Stanley said, you should only test that the Controller returns the appropriate result, not that the other layers, database etc. are working.

However, to create the Controller in a Unit Test use:

```
var controller = new AdminController(any arguments/contexts here);
```